# Cannot connect to wireless wifi and cannot manually install drivers

Tags: networking, software-installation, wifi, drivers, broadcom

I've been trying to set up SparkyLinux for the past hours, and I can't seem to get the internet connection working. I'm dual booting it on a USB through my Mac, and it seems that the drivers for my wireless card are not supported.

Since the needed wireless drivers were not installed on my system, the only way to download them was through an internet connection. Therefore, I tried downloading the packages on my Mac and then manually moving them to the USB. Here's the problem: whenever I plug said USB into my mac, I get an error message that reads "The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." As a result, I can't move any files into the USB.

My computer uses a Broadcom BCM4360 with a PCI ID of 14e4:43a0.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless card requires firmware installed by the firmware-b43-installer package.

(offline install)

Note: Requires access to a Debian workstation with internet connection & two USB sticks.

On another Debian machine, run:

> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

Copy the contents of /lib/firmware/b43 to another USB stick

Run the Debian installer in text mode. When you get to the stage "detecting network hardware", switch to the second tty (fn+alt+f2), press enter to activate, and run:

> mkdir /lib/firmware/b43

Mount the second USB stick

> mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt

Copy the firmware to the ramdisk's filesystem

> cp -a /mnt/. /lib/firmware/b43

Switch back to the installer with (fn+alt+f1)

Now your wireless should be functional.